# What is the correct way to loop while error occurs

Tags: loops, rust

I am quite new to Rust, and I'm still trying to be sure I understand principles doing a small project creating a server that uses a TcpStream. The server asks for a client for a code, which has to be 8 characters long. If it's not, it shall ask again for a new code. Here is what I have so far :

```rust
fn loby_matcher(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<(String, usize), >{
    let mut game_code = String::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);
    let len : usize = reader.read_line(&mut game_code)?;
    match len {
        8 => len,
        _ => return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "wrong game code")),
    };
    Ok((game_code, len))
}

pub fn create_game_matcher(mut stream: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<()>{
    println!("Creating a new game! Waiting for the code.");
    let game_code: String;
    let len: usize;
    loop {
        (game_code, len) = match loby_matcher(&mut stream) {
            Ok(game_code) => break (game_code, len),
            Err(e) => {
                stream.write("Wrong code\n".as_bytes());
                (String::new(),0)
            }
        };
    };
    println!("Received : {} size {}", game_code, len);
    // println!("Closing connection now I guess?");
    Ok(())
}

fn start_server(address: &str, port: &str) -> std::io::Result<()>{
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", address, port))?;

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        // not using ? as we do not want to stop the server for wrong connection
        let stream = stream.unwrap(); 
        thread::spawn(move || {
            create_game_matcher(stream);
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The loop asking for a new code when an error occurs seems wrong, but I cannot figure out a way of doing that.
Also, I know I should create a custom error in order to be able to make a difference between a wrong code and an I/O error on my TCPstream, which I will do later.
What would be the right way of looping while a specific error occurs?

### Edit

If you see anything wrong in the code, do not hesitate to tell me how I could improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking how to resolve the issue in `create_game_matcher`. If so, then you need to move your assignment further out.

To compare the error inside [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html), can be cumbersome. You can check the kind using `e.kind() == ErrorKind::Other`. However, the actual error could be anything, and doesn't require implementing `PartialEq` for `&str`. The easiest is probably just to do `e.to_string() == "wrong game code"`.

But like you mention, the most idiomatic approach would be to create a your own error type.

```rust
pub fn create_game_matcher(mut stream: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("Creating a new game! Waiting for the code.");

    let (game_code, len) = loop {
        match loby_matcher(&mut stream) {
            Ok(game_code) => break game_code,
            // Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Other && e.to_string() == "wrong game code" => {
            // or just (for ease of use)
            Err(e) if e.to_string() == "wrong game code" => {
                stream.write("Wrong code\n".as_bytes())?;
            }
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        };
    };

    println!("Received : {} size {}", game_code, len);
    // println!("Closing connection now I guess?");
    Ok(())
}
```

Since you want to loop until `loby_matcher` succeeds, then `(String::new(), 0)` can be removed. You also forgot to check whether `stream.write` failed, so I've added an `?`.

---

Alternatively, given that you always break after the assignment, you could also express it like this:

```rust
pub fn create_game_matcher(mut stream: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("Creating a new game! Waiting for the code.");

    let game_code: String;
    let len: usize;
    loop {
        match loby_matcher(&mut stream) {
            Ok((game_code_, len_)) => {
                game_code = game_code_;
                len = len_;
                break;
            }
            Err(e) if e.to_string() == "wrong game code" => {
                stream.write("Wrong code\n".as_bytes())?;
            }
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        };
    }

    println!("Received : {} size {}", game_code, len);
    // println!("Closing connection now I guess?");
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I'm trying to implement a custom error now. Could you confirm that I need to implement the form trait from Interrupted error?

Comment: @Qwark Yes, you'd need to `impl From<...> for MyError` to be able to do `?`. If you add your custom error to the question, I can help you out :)